# Can't update items in parent page using loaded child page

Tags: .net, asp.net, jquery, visual-studio-2008

Hey guys, this is more something like "what to do?" than a question in fact... here it is:

I have a page in which users can execute selected services.. each of these services are different full .aspx pages (there's a lot of them).

the page is divided in 3 sections, as you can see in the picture:

[alt text http://geocities.com/gth_sal/question.png](http://geocities.com/gth_sal/question.png)

Panel A: lists the selected services (item 1,2, 3) in a gridview with datasource and inside an updatepanel.
Panel B It's a div where I load the .aspx services pages with jquery's .load() function
(each separated .aspx service file have a button to execute the service)

What I Want to do is to reload items in PanelA and PanelC once a service is executed to check them as executed (like item 1), But since the ExecuteButton is in a secondary page i can't use it's events to update in parent page..

Is there any way to do this? Or maybe another totally different solution to this?
Maybe without the jquery..

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Xandy's answer, you can access the parent window from the client side with;
   window.parent.

So basically you can do window.parent.jQuery(".MySelectorToRefresh").load("myURL");

HTH

Comment: hmmm the part i need to refresh isn't related to a specific URL.. it's part of the entire page..

Answer (score 0):

I did not really set up the test case for your situation, but I think you can try with this and let me know how's it.
First, supposing your whole page (that contain panel a,b,c) is called index.aspx. Then you can setup a callback function for updating panel A and C. eg

```
UpdateCallBack = function(updateParameters){};
```

Now, I am not sure when are you going to update the panels, if once the serviceItem1.aspx is done loading and you update the panels, you can bind in to [AJAX success event](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxSuccess#callback). But, if the user needs to do something in Panel B and then Panel A,C will update, you can just call the UpdateCallBack function that we setup before, in the index.aspx. I think it is ok to call that function from the contents of Panel B.